# How can I change Edit Text´s selection color?

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Description:**

When you keep pressed an edit text (in order to select text), an indicator appears (i don´t know it´s name).

[image]

**Question:**

How can i edit it´s color?

**Thanks so much for reading.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this to your style.xml

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- change values below to make same eefect for all EditTexts ->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
</style>
<!-- also you can create different styles with values above for many different views ->
```

Comment: Nice, you solved my problem. Thanks you so much for helping.

Comment: No problem, my dear friend)